# Do you read 10 pages IN a book or 10 pages OF a book or 10 pages FROM a book?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is correct? And if more than one is correct, is there a difference in meaning between them?

1. You should read at least 10 pages in Smith (2015) before each meeting
2. You should read at least 10 pages of Smith (2015) before each meeting
3. You should read at least 10 pages from Smith (2015) before each meeting

Comment: By usage, "of" is the clear winner: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+several+pages+in%2Cread+several+pages+of%2Cread+several+pages+from%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cread%20several%20pages%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20several%20pages%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20several%20pages%20from%3B%2Cc0), and feels the most natural to me. None feel wrong.

Comment: They're all pretty equal. To me "of" sounds the least natural. I don't think I use that but wouldn't think twice if I heard someone else use it. I think I use "in" most of the time but if I sit back and think about it I think "from" sounds the classiest. I should start using "from" more often. I have a feeling "from" is very British.

Comment: @DKNguyen - As a British English speaker, I would say 'read ten pages of a book' - 'read a chapter of _Smith_', but 'This passage is from Smith's book on XXX'.

Comment: Thank you all! Much appreciated!!

Comment: I think "of" is usual if you're reading a book (from start to finish). You'd say "I read ten pages of Wuthering Heights last night" or just "I read ten pages of my book" (meaning the book I'm currently reading). The rest naturally refer to excerpts. So "of" is most natural. Not sure I can find any references to support my intuition.

Answer (score 1):

You can say any of these three sentences without violating any rules. Here are some related comments:

(1) **of** usually indicates possession, so implicit in that instruction is the assumption that you own Smith's book.

(2) **in** is a very common use when you're talking about printed material. For example, "I read it in the newspaper." When you speak about electronic reading materials, you typically use **on**, for example, "I read it on the Internet."

(3) **read from** is also an idiom meaning to read aloud from something. So if someone asked you to read a bible passage aloud, they would ask you to "read from" the bible.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting what you say about "from" – now that you mention it, it seems very clear that reading **from** a book implies reading aloud...